# RUBY - can arr.max_by(&:length) return last instance if lengths are equal?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I've solved this problem but would like to clean it up by using arr.max_by(&:length), is this possible?

```
def longest_streak(str)
    length = 0
    longest = ''
    hash = Hash.new('')
    str.each_char.with_index do |char, index|
        hash[char] += char
    end
    #hash.values.max_by(&:length)
    
    hash.values.each do |string| 
        if string.length >= length
            length = string.length 
            longest = string
        end
    end
    longest
end

p longest_streak('a')           # => 'a'
p longest_streak('accccbbb')    # => 'cccc'
p longest_streak('aaaxyyyyyzz') # => 'yyyyy
p longest_streak('aaabbb')      # => 'bbb'
p longest_streak('abc')         # => 'c'
```

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I'm happy to add slice_when and chunk_while to the tool bag.

Answer (score 3):

In order to use `max_by(&:length)` you need a collection of streaks.

This can be generated via [`each_char`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#each_char-method) and [`chunk_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#chunk_while-method):

```
str = "accccbbb"

str.each_char          #=> ["a", "c", "c", "c", "c", "b", "b", "b"]
   .chunk_while(&:==)  #=> [["a"], ["c", "c", "c", "c"], ["b", "b", "b"]]
   .max_by(&:length)   #=> ["c", "c", "c", "c"]
   .join               #=> "cccc"
```

Note that the above returns the longest run of *consecutive* letters.

If there are multiple matches and you want the last one, you can simply [`reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#reverse-method) the string:

```
str = "aabbcc"

str.each_char.chunk_while(&:==).max_by(&:length).join
#=> "aa"

str.reverse.each_char.chunk_while(&:==).max_by(&:length).join
#=> "cc"
```

Comment: You may wish to use [Enumerable#reverse_each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reverse_each) (which returns an enumerator) rather than `reverse`, to avoid the creation of a temporary array. Readers, note that [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) could be used in place of `chunk_while`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I did that on purpose. `reverse_each` reads the enumerated values into a temporary array and enumerates them again from last to first. I assume reversing a string is a more lightweight operation.

Comment: I find that odd, but I expect you're right, that you've read the code, but I don't see why Ruby would create a temporary array rather than just maintaining a pointer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the docs say so. I think that’s because enumerable has to implement `reverse_each` on top of `each` which only goes in one direction.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that `String#gsub` be used with a regular expression.

```
def longest_run(str)
  str.gsub(/(.)\1*/).with_object('') do |s,longest|
    longest.replace(s) if s.size >= longest.size
  end
end
```

```
longest_run('a')           # => 'a'
longest_run('accccbbb')    # => 'cccc'
longest_run('aaaxyyyyyzz') # => 'yyyyy
longest_run('aaabbb')      # => 'bbb'
longest_run('abc')         # => 'c'
```

The uses the form of [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) that takes a single argument (the regular expression) but has no block, and therefore returns an enumerator. With this form `gsub` merely generates matches and performs no substitutions.

The regular expression reads, "match any character and save to capture group 1, that character to be followed by zero or more characters equal to the contents of capture group 1 (i.e., the same character)".

If desired, one could replace with `longest.replace(s)` with `longest[0..-1] = s`.

Notice that, when there is a tie for maximum substring length, the first, rather than last, longest string can be obtained by changing `>=` to `>`.

---

Let's compare the computational efficiency of this method with @Stefan's method.

```
require 'fruity'
```

```
def chunk1(str)
  str.reverse.each_char.chunk_while(&:==).max_by(&:length).join
end
```

```
def chunk2(str)
  str.each_char.reverse_each.chunk_while(&:==).max_by(&:length).join
end
```

```
def test(n)
  str = n.times.map { ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].sample }.join
  compare do
    gsub    { longest_run(str) }
    chunk_1 { chunk1(str) }
    chunk_2 { chunk2(str) }
  end
end
```

```
test   10
Running each test 512 times. Test will take about 1 second.
gsub is faster than chunk_1 by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
chunk_1 is similar to chunk_2
```

```
test  100
Running each test 64 times. Test will take about 1 second.
gsub is faster than chunk_1 by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
chunk_1 is similar to chunk_2
```

```
test 1000
Running each test 8 times. Test will take about 1 second.
gsub is faster than chunk_2 by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
chunk_2 is similar to chunk_1
```

```
test 10000
Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
gsub is faster than chunk_1 by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0%
chunk_1 is similar to chunk_2
```

I re-ran these tests several times. For `n = 1000` and `n = 10000` the results were consistent. For `n = 100` `gsub` was generally faster than the `chunk`s by 10%, but sometimes they were similar. Results varied greatly for `n = 10` with what I show as `gsub`'s advantage being roughly the average result.

There seems to be a widespread belief that the use of regular expressions is generally inefficient when compared to alternative methods, but often, as here (apparently) that is not always the case. A more dramatic example of this point is @Schwern's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66172388/ruby-rails-keyword-search-to-filter-out-partial-words/66180616?noredirect=1#comment117006482_66180616).

This provides no evidence that the efficiency of Stefan's method depends on whether `reverse` or `reverse_each` is used.